# Does forwarded SMS contain the original sender's tel number?

Tags: android, sms, pdu

Let's say user1 received an SMS from tel1. Then he forwarded it to user2. Will user2 be able to extract tel1 from the SMS he received?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is *no*, such information does not get forwarded to the receiver.